# proj4js not convert y

Tags: openlayers-2, proj, coordinate-system

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:2322"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=36 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +no_defs ";

Proj4js.defs["EPSG:4326"] = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";

alert(feature.geometry.getVertices()[0].x);
alert(feature.geometry.getVertices()[0].y);
var point = new Proj4js.Point(feature.geometry.getVertices()[0].x, feature.geometry.getVertices()[0].y);


//Define the source Coord Sys 
var src = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:4326");
//Define the destination Coord Sys   
var dst = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:2322");

var gk=  Proj4js.transform(src, dst, point);
alert(gk);
```

i can get x and y cordinates but when i convert them to epsg 2322. x will change but y is always zero.

i found thats code but it is not converting correct

---

```
  Proj4js.defs["EPSG:2322"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=36 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +towgs84=-87,-98,-121,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs";
        Proj4js.defs["EPSG:4326"] = "+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs";
        Proj4js.defs["GOOGLE"] = "+proj=merc +a=6378137 +b=6378137 +lat_ts=0.0 +lon_0=0.0 +x_0=0.0 +y_0=0 +k=1.0 +units=m +nadgrids=@null +no_defs";
        Proj4js.defs["EPSG:900913"] = Proj4js.defs["GOOGLE"];





        //Define the source Coord Sys 
        var src = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:900913");
        //Define the destination Coord Sys   
        var dst = new Proj4js.Proj("EPSG:2322");
        var point = new Proj4js.Point(feature.geometry.getVertices()[0].x, feature.geometry.getVertices()[0].y);
        Proj4js.transform(src, dst, point);
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd add the `+towgs84` parameters in `EPSG:2322` definition in order to have a quite correct transformation (accuracy: 2 meters), as reported [here](http://www.epsg-registry.org/report.htm?type=selection&entity=urn%3aogc%3adef%3acoordinateOperation%3aEPSG%3a:1783&reportDetail=short&style=urn%3auuid%3areport-style%3adefault-with-code&style_name=OGP%20Default%20With%20Code&title=) (EPSG Geodetic Parameter Dataset):

```
Proj4js.defs["EPSG:2322"] = "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=36 +k=1 +x_0=500000 +y_0=0 +ellps=intl +units=m +towgs84=-84.1,-101.8,-129.7,0,0,0.468,1.05 +no_defs";
```